# tar error when including a dotfile

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I need to tar some files, where one is a dotfile.

```bsh
FILE1=/tmp/foo/.env
FILE2=/tmp/foo/docker-compose.yml

FILES="${FILE1#/} ${FILE2#/}"

tar -C / -cf /tmp/foo/files.tar "$FILES"
```

The variable substitution avoids the `tar: Removing leading '/' from member names` warning, and simplifies untarring.

But I get this error:

> tar: tmp/foo/.env tmp/foo/docker-compose.yml: Cannot stat: No such file or directory

Hardcoding the paths works: `tar -C / -cf /tmp/foo/files.tar tmp/foo/.env tmp/foo/docker-compose.yml`.

So I assume the problem is in handling that dotfile, or something to do with escaping?

Comment: If you like to archive two files, you should give two file arguments instead of just one.

Comment: If you put things into double quotes, the result is one single argument.

Comment: @schily Thanks, just tried your way and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the shell expands `"$FILES"`, the space loses its syntactical value. So the `tar` command receives `tmp/foo/.env tmp/foo/docker-compose.yml` as a single path.

Just as

```
file='a b'
touch "$file"
```

will create file `a b`, not two files `a` and `b`.

So, as suggested in comment, you should use different variables for different files: `tar -C / -cf /tmp/foo/files.tar "${FILE1#/}" "${FILE2#/}"`.

---

The fact that directly running `tar -C / -cf /tmp/foo/files.tar tmp/foo/.env tmp/foo/docker-compose.yml` works is because the spaces have syntactical value there, separating one argument from another. To the "human eyes", the same space will be produced after the expansion of `"$FILES"` to `tmp/foo/.env tmp/foo/docker-compose.yml`, but in this case the space has no special meaning because of the quoting, so the whole value will be treated as a single path.